# bash array from find command length

Tags: arrays, shell, size

I have the following code:

```
filelist="$(find $name -type f | sort)";
echo "$filelist";
echo "${#filelist[@]}"
```

My array contains many elements but the last command says my array contains only one element. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use parentheses to have bash recognize it as an array.

```
filelist=($(find $name -type f | sort))
echo ${#filelist[@]}
```

Comment: Thanks, the one you wrote works, but it doesn't as I use quotes. Why?

Comment: because quotes make it into a single word, and you want the array elements to be individual words.